# How do I set attributes for an XML element with Python?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I am using ElementTree to build an XML file.

When I try to set an element's attribute with `ET.SubElement().__setattr__()`, I get the error `AttributeError: __setattr__`.

```python
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
summary = open(Summary.xml, 'w')
root = ET.Element('Summary')
ET.SubElement(root, 'TextSummary')
ET.SubElement(root,'TextSummary').__setattr__('Status','Completed') # Error occurs here
tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 
tree.write(summary)
summary.close()
```

After code execution, my XML should resemble the following:

```xml
<Summary>
    <TextSummary Status = 'Completed'/>
</Summary>
```

How do I add attributes to an XML element with Python using `xml.etree.cElementTree`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should be doing:

```
ET.SubElement(root,'TextSummary').set('Status','Completed')
```

The [Etree documentation shows usage](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file).

Comment: Is there a way to set attributes for a root element?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Yes: just do `root.set('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: It turns out you can [specify attributes as part of the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668871/3357935).

Answer (score 16):

You can specify attributes for an [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) or [`SubElement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement) during creation with keyword arguments.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('Summary')
ET.SubElement(root, 'TextSummary', Status='Completed')
```

XML:

```xml
<Summary>
    <TextSummary Status="Completed"/>
</Summary>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`.set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set) to add attributes to an existing element.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('Summary')
sub = ET.SubElement(root, 'TextSummary')
sub.set('Status', 'Completed')
```

XML:

```xml
<Summary>
    <TextSummary Status="Completed"/>
</Summary>
```

---

**Technical Explanation:**

The constructors for [`Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) and [`SubElement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement) include `**extra`, which accepts attributes as keyword arguments.

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)
xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement(parent, tag, attrib={}, **extra)
```

This allows you to add an arbitrary number of attributes.

```
root = ET.Element('Summary', Date='2018/07/02', Timestamp='11:44am')
# <Summary Date = "2018/07/02" Timestamp = "11:44am">
```

You can also use use [`.set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set) to add attributes to a pre-existing element. However, this can only add one element at a time. ([As suggested by Thomas Orozco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796341/3357935)).

```
root = ET.Element('Summary')
root.set('Date', '2018/07/02')
root.set('Timestamp', '11:44am')
# <Summary Date = "2018/07/02" Timestamp = "11:44am">
```

---

**Full Example:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('school', name='Willow Creek High')
ET.SubElement(root, 'student', name='Jane Doe', grade='9')
print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
# <school name="Willow Creek High"><student grade="9" name="Jane Doe" /></school>
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to set multiple attributes in single line is below.
I wrote this code for SVG XML creation:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

svg = ET.Element('svg', attrib={'height':'210','width':'500'})
g = ET.SubElement(svg,'g', attrib={'x':'10', 'y':'12','id':'groupName'})
line = ET.SubElement(g, 'line', attrib={'x1':'0','y1':'0','x2':'200','y2':'200','stroke':'red'})

print(ET.tostring(svg, encoding="us-ascii", method="xml"))
```