# How to create an xml attribute xml:id using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I'm using python to create xml files, and I need to create an attribute like this

```
<element xml:id="something"/> some text
```

I specifically used lcml because I need some text after the unique tag, I couldn't do it using DOM. If this is possible using DOM it would be great.
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For adding attribute you should be doing:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
ET.SubElement(root,'element').set('xml:id','something')
```

For adding text:

```
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for element in root.findall('element'):
    element.text = str("some text")
tree.write('output.xml')
```

The [Etree documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file) shows usage.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18796280/set-attribute-to-element-in-python

Comment: well, I still need to write some text after the tag: <element xml:id="something"/> texttexttext

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tail` property:

```
etree_element.tail = ' some text'
```